# Flash Pro project file corrupted after a crash

Tags: flash, actionscript, crash

I was editing a project with Flash CS6, before the crash everything was fully edited and saved correctly. However there was a crash when I was away for lunch break.

After a crash, I tried to open the project file again, everything loads, but settings are corrupted. Especially for Publish Profile: Target. Originally this was set to 11.4, and now is blank. Even I try to select 11.4 it will reset back to blank. All my TLF texts become invisible. When I try to create new TLF text, it says publish profile must set to target 10 or above, but there is no way I can set it (keep resetting back to blank). Another thing that happen is there r a lot of compilation error. Before the crash, no compilation error at all.

Some of the compilation error after the crash:

```
implicitImports, Line 1 1172: Definition __AS3__.vec:Vector could not be found.

implicitImports, Line 3 1172: Definition flash.desktop could not be found.

implicitImports, Line 10 1172: Definition flash.globalization could not be found.

implicitImports, Line 13 1172: Definition flash.net.drm could not be found.

implicitImports, Line 17 1172: Definition flash.sensors could not be found.

implicitImports, Line 20 1172: Definition flash.text.ime could not be found.

implicitImports, Line 21 1172: Definition flash.text.engine could not be found.
```

Is there anyway you can recover this project file?? Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, I fixed this issue by repair the Fla file with WinRAR and removed file "PublishSettings.xml" inside the fla.

PublishSettings.xml does not even seems to be contain anything useful, but I guess this was the problem.